Can't refresh a Livewire component after wire:click button
I can't seem to get my LikeCounter livewire component to be able to refresh after i clicked a button that triggers a wire:click event.
My LikeCounter Livewire component:
class LikeCounter extends Component
{
    public $id,$photo,$like_count,$like_exist;

    protected $listeners = [
        'refreshParent' => '$refresh',
      ];
      
    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->photo = Photo::find($this->id);
        $this->like_count = LikeCount::count();
        if(LikeCount::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('photo_id',$this->id)->get()->isEmpty() == false ){
            $this->like_exist = 1;
        }
        else{
            $this->like_exist = 0;
        }
    }
    public function like()
    {
        $this->photo = Photo::find($this->id);
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $this->photo->likes()->create([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'photo_id'=> $this->photo->photo_id
        ]);
        $this->dispatch('refreshParent');
    }
    public function unlike()
    {
        $this->photo = Photo::find($this->id);
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $like = new LikeCount;
        $like->where('photo_id',$this->id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->delete();
        $this->dispatch('refreshParent');
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.like-counter');
    }
}

My like-counter.blade.php Blade file:
<div>
    @if($like_exist != 1)
    <button type='button' class='button btn' wire:click='like'>Like...</button>
    @else
    <button type='button' class='button btn' wire:click='unlike'>Unlike...</button>
    @endif
    <p>{{ $like_count }} people liked this photo</p>
</div>

I expected that after clicking the Like/Unlike button, the wire:click event will trigger the method specified in my <button> element and then reloads the component to reflect the change in the component, but instead it does not refresh after the trigger and i need to do a full reload to get the updated results.
From this, i think there are three possible problems with my code:

my like-counter.blade.php file is written incorrectly and i need to merge it into a single button with a toggle change (thus requiring my like() and unlike() method to merge)
my refresh method in LikeCounter component doesnt work as it should

if neither of these are correct, how should i refactor my code?

the main function that wil display/update the new count of likes is called mount() when you go to the official livewire docs and then to the rendering of components you wil find
In Livewire components, you use mount() instead of a class constructor __construct() like you may be used to. NB: mount() is only ever called when the component is first mounted and will not be called again even when the component is refreshed or rerendered.

@oelimoe this gives me the idea to both merge my like() and unlike() method into my mount() method. I use livewire 3.x but the docs on the usage of mount() method remains similar. However, i still want to display the change after triggering the method, not after a full page reload. should i use the boot()method to display the change?

@oelimoe Correction: actually i need to put my like() and unlike() method into a new method. However, i was thinking that the problem might not be on the mount() itself but rather how the data is presented in the blade view, thus i might not need to merge my like() and unlike() method at all if possible.

combining the like and unlike method isnt an issue since it is just an if statement checking if user has liked. I couldnt test this code myself since i had no real database like you did but what i did test is how like and dislike could work. so what i tried was in the like function i did $this->like_count += 1; and in the dislike it was $this->like_count -= 1 and set the $this->like_exists to 0 or 1 depending on it having like in the blade i changed nothing. The result of this was that it showed '1 people liked this post' and when disliked '0 people like this post'

so it did get updated when it was changed in the like method. then i was looking for when it would change in your code it was only when mount() was called that the like count got an update. and this function cant be refreshed so it only changes when you open the page not when code is executed

@oelimoe the $this->like_count variable isnt the issue that i was looking for, but rather how to refresh the data after the like() or unlike() method has been triggered, like when you click the like button in a social media, the data in the html should be changed immediately after you clicked the button, and the button itself should also be changed to 'unlike' or 'remove like' so that you can remove a like if you accidentally clicked the like button.

what you are saying is that it isnt immedeatly updated <p>{{ $like_count }} people liked this photo</p> this is what isnt updated is what you are saying but what updates the vatiable is the mount() function if you add $this->like_count = LikeCount::count(); at the end of the like and dislike function it should be live updated

@oelimoe i understand now, you were trying to say that i forgot to update both $this->like_exist variable (which should be updated to 1 when the like() method is triggered and vice versa) and $this->like_count variable (which should be added to both methods).

although, i do have the option to use the boot() method instead, but i feel like if this is not needed.

the boot method is something you need to figure out for yourself since i believe in both cases the code would work so it is a personal choiche of how you want it to work i wil try to make an official answer now

The main issuee seems to be that $this->like_count and $this->like_exists are only called opun once when the mount() function is called. This function cant be refreshed and only be called once.
solution 1:
You can have the same kind of function as mount() like boot() which can be called opun a second time. which will fix the issue.
solution 2:
you can update the $this->like_count and $this->like_exists at the end of the functions like() and unlike() like this:
class LikeCounter extends Component
{
    public $id,$photo,$like_count,$like_exist;

    protected $listeners = [
        'refreshParent' => '$refresh',
      ];
      
    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->photo = Photo::find($this->id);
        $this->like_count = LikeCount::count();
        if(LikeCount::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('photo_id',$this->id)->get()->isEmpty() == false ){
            $this->like_exist = 1;
        }
        else{
            $this->like_exist = 0;
        }
    }
    public function like()
    {
        $this->photo = Photo::find($this->id);
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $this->photo->likes()->create([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'photo_id'=> $this->photo->photo_id
        ]);
        $this->like_count = LikeCount::count();
        if(LikeCount::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('photo_id',$this->id)->get()->isEmpty() == false ){
            $this->like_exist = 1;
        }
        else{
            $this->like_exist = 0;
        }
        $this->dispatch('refreshParent');
    }
    public function unlike()
    {
        $this->photo = Photo::find($this->id);
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $like = new LikeCount;
        $like->where('photo_id',$this->id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->delete();
         $this->like_count = LikeCount::count();
        if(LikeCount::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('photo_id',$this->id)->get()->isEmpty() == false ){
            $this->like_exist = 1;
        }
        else{
            $this->like_exist = 0;
        }
        $this->dispatch('refreshParent');
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.like-counter');
    }
}


this one actually really helped me, although since the like() and unlike() method also add and delete comment respectively, the if statement in those two method are unnecessary. anyway though, thanks for the help!

i believe you are able to edit the answer yourself if you want to because i dont completely understand what you mean but it was no problem i am here for the reputation and just love to help people
